# Meaning of "T-vector of time series values"?

Tags: bayesian, time-series

I am currently studying a paper on Hierarchical Bayesian space-time models. In that, we have denoted $Y(s,t)$ to be the process of interest ate location $s$ and time $t$ in a gridded space-time. $Y(s, )$ is denoted as to be the T-vector of time series values at site $s$ where $T$ is the total number of time points.

Can someone explain to me what does this statement means? -  **T-vector of time series values**.
Thank you.

Comment: I'd suspect that this denotes the vector $(Y(s,t_1), Y(s,t_2), \dots ,Y(s,t_T))$ (here written down as row vector, but its transpose may also be used). This means, for a fixed site $s$, the finite series of all measurements at this site. Is this interpretation consistent with the formulas which follow in the paper?

Comment: I haven't read the complete paper but here is the link if you want to see it - http://www.stat.missouri.edu/~wikle/WikleBerlinerCressie1998.pdf -  section 2 "Notation" 3rd paragrapgh

Comment: I've skimmed the paper and as they are defining $Y(,t)$ as a matrix which containes the measurements over the whole grid for a fixed time, my suspection grows further. When skimming, I didn't actually find a place where they used any of these notations (but I was just skimming, not reading thoroughly).